# Use an external object as plotted size with maps and geom_point

Tags: r, maps

I have working code that refers to a csv (`mapdata`) to plot two sets of data on top of a US map.  I am interested in building in a user input that allows a user running the script to select which columns of data they want to plot on the map, and update the `geom_point()` command accordingly.

I have been working with `as.numeric` and `readline()` to categorize the request for each set of data

```
# select the first variable to use:
selectFIRST <- function()  { 
  as.numeric(readline("Please enter a number to select the first: \n 1-Clinical_Trial\n 2- Comparative_Study\n 3-Evaluation_Studies\n 4-In_Vitro\n 5- JOURNAL_ARTICLE\n 6-Consensus_Development_Conference\n 7-Guideline\n 8-Research_Support_NonUSGovt\n 9-Total>>> ")) 
} 
Input_First <- selectFIRST() 
print(Input_First)

# define the first variable based on numeric input
First <- "error"
if(Input_First == 1){
    First <- 'Clinical_Trial'
} else if(Input_First == 2){.....
```

and so on, resulting in two variables (`First` and `Second`).
I then define

```
all_states <- map_data("state")
g <- ggplot()  
g <- g + geom_polygon(data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),
                      colour="grey", fill="white" )

print(g)

plot.new()

mapPoints <- g + geom_point(data = mapdata,
                            aes(x=lon, y=lat, size = [FIRST or SECOND]), 
                        color = "#1100e7", bg = "#43c9e7", alpha = .75,
                            shape = 21) + scale_size(range=c(3,15))
```

What I would like to do is make the size variable within `aes` refer to the `FIRST` and `SECOND` variables designated outside the `geom_point` function.  Is this possible given the `geom_point()` structure?

Comment: You probably want to use `aes_string`. Also, for the earlier sections of your code, you probably want to investigate the functions `menu` and `switch`.

Comment: thanks very much @joran.  most helpful and quick reply